# Is the "X" delete button on the homescreen part of the SDK?

Tags: iphone, image, button, ibooks

So when you want to delete an app from the Home Screen, or delete a book from iBooks, when you get into "Edit Mode" there is a little itty bitty X in the upper left hand corner of the app icon/book/whatever.

Is this button part of the SDK?

And... if not (I'm pretty sure it isn't), does anybody know an Apple sample project that might contain the X image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try looking in the Springboard.app. (Springboard is the home screen in iOS.) It should be located somewhere like:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator*X.Y.Z*.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/

**EDIT:** per the comment below, the location of the images for the 4.1 simulator sdk is:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/closebox.png /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/closebox\@2x.png

Comment: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/closebox.png 

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/closebox\@2x.png

Comment: It is kind of remarkable that Apple hasn't made these ubiquitous icons more easily accessible within the SDK, the way that the standard icons are available in Android

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in drawing this using Quartz, the following code is pulled from a CALayer that I created to render this kind of delete button:

```
#define SPACETOEXPANDDELETELAYERFORSHADOW 4.0f
#define FRACTIONOFVIEWFORSTARTANDSTOPOFCROSSLINES 0.38

- (void)renderAsVectorInContext:(CGContextRef)context;
{
    if (strokeColor == NULL)
        return;

    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinBevel);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeWidth);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGRect currentFrame = self.bounds;
    currentFrame = CGRectInset(currentFrame, SPACETOEXPANDDELETELAYERFORSHADOW, SPACETOEXPANDDELETELAYERFORSHADOW);

    CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f), 2.0f);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(currentFrame.origin.x + strokeWidth, currentFrame.origin.y + strokeWidth, currentFrame.size.width - (2.0f * strokeWidth), currentFrame.size.height - (2.0f * strokeWidth)));
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(currentFrame.origin.x + strokeWidth, currentFrame.origin.y + strokeWidth, currentFrame.size.width - (2.0f * strokeWidth), currentFrame.size.height - (2.0f * strokeWidth)));

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.3f * strokeWidth);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, currentFrame.origin.x + FRACTIONOFVIEWFORSTARTANDSTOPOFCROSSLINES * currentFrame.size.width, currentFrame.origin.y + FRACTIONOFVIEWFORSTARTANDSTOPOFCROSSLINES * currentFrame.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentFrame.origin.x + (1.0f - FRACTIONOFVIEWFORSTARTANDSTOPOFCROSSLINES) * currentFrame.size.width, currentFrame.origin.y + (1.0f - FRACTIONOFVIEWFORSTARTANDSTOPOFCROSSLINES) * currentFrame.size.height);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, currentFrame.origin.x + (1.0f - FRACTIONOFVIEWFORSTARTANDSTOPOFCROSSLINES) * currentFrame.size.width, currentFrame.origin.y + FRACTIONOFVIEWFORSTARTANDSTOPOFCROSSLINES * currentFrame.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentFrame.origin.x + FRACTIONOFVIEWFORSTARTANDSTOPOFCROSSLINES * currentFrame.size.width, currentFrame.origin.y + (1.0f - FRACTIONOFVIEWFORSTARTANDSTOPOFCROSSLINES) * currentFrame.size.height);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

in this case, `strokeColor` is a white CGColorRef, the layer is 31 x 31, and the `strokeWidth` is 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this image, just:

- Cut it from somewhere
- Make the background transparent with photoshop
- Add the image to a custom UIButton.

Sorry I don't remember any project that uses it...